# Minus one month off of date

Tags: php

$_month is set to 05. I want to minus one month off of it.

I am using the following:

```
$newdate = strtotime ( '-1 months' , $_month ) ;
            $newdate = date ( 'm' , $newdate );
            echo $newdate;
```

However, my result is coming out at 12.

What am I doing wrong, when it should be 04?

Comment: value of `$_month` is what? `05` or `"05"`? If `05` then it's treated as an octal.

Comment: Given that strtotime expects a unix timesstamp as the second argument (if one is provided), that `05` will be interpreted as 5 seconds past midnight (UTC) on 1st January 1970.... -1 month from then will be December 1969; hence month 12

Comment: So if I was to go this route, I would need to push a full date and then I could minus one month off the value I push as the month?

Comment: try `$newdate = strtotime('-1 months', strtotime("2017-$_month-01"));`

Comment: [Using DateTime::createFromFormat() to tell PHP that your value is a month number](https://3v4l.org/IUOAI)

Answer (score 0):

Solved after many attempts, this will give me the flexibility that I need.

```
$pDate = strtotime('1-'.$_month.'-2017 - 1 month');
echo date('m',$pDate);
```